# how to batch find and replace bone by regex with multiple name list

Tags: unreal-engine

I try to make my own bone rename list for Daz3d character to Ue4
by using Blender's batch rename tool with regex.
The outcome I want is to change bone names separately in a list, for example:

- *abdomenLower* → *spine_01* and
- *abdomenUpper* → *spine_02* and so on.

I use a setting that works in Notepad++.
The *search for* is `(abdomenLower)|(abdomenUpper)` and the *replace with* is `(?1spine_01)(?2spine_02)`.

But in Blender, it works only the search phrase. The replace phrase just replaces both matches with `(?1spine_01)(?2spine_02)` and `(?1spine_01)(?2spine_02).001`.

Does anyone know the proper regex for the replace phrase in Blender?

Comment: Have a look at the linked question above. The first matched group for the regex is referenced by `\1` not by `?1`.

Comment: thank you blunder

Comment: but the outcome still not what I want.
now the bone name is go
(spine_01)(abdomenUpperspine_02)
(abdomenLowerspine_01)(spine_02)

what I want is to change it seprately
abdomenLower > spine_01
abdomenUpper > spine_02

Comment: Sorry, then this is not a duplicate and solves only a part of your problem. I've voted to reopen it again. -- I've tried your example in Notepad++. Is the *replace with* correct? Shouldn't it be `(?1spine_01)(?2spine_02)` without the `|`? Because with the `|` the replacement does this: `abdomenLower` -> `spine_01|` and `abdomenUpper` -> `|spine_02`. -- Blender might use Python regex? (not sure). But if it's not possible to use regex then you still can use a script in Blender.

Comment: yes it's not with the | . I just copy the wrong one by my experiment. sorry about that because English is not my native language so I always use copy a lot. I will re edit the question. Also at this point I also think the batch rename will not work with notepad++ solution because how it design. And phyton script is beyond my understanding.

Comment: but actually I already use other third party batch script that someone already make long time a go to rename these bone by covert the .fbx file.
it's just not comfortable to do it when you edit the model a lot of time and reimport it